# How can i get my JS to return true or false?

Tags: php, forms, return, return-value

I want to **return either TRUE or FALSE** when the variable '**f**' i FALSE. But the return never reaches the browser and the form does its default action.

**How can i get my ELSE to return a value?**
I have tried to hard code a return value instead of writing '**return myFunction();**' this works but it doesn't help me as i need the return from '**myFunction()**'.

Don't think to much about what the code is supposed to do, it doesn't make sense, its just for demonstration.

```
$('#theForm').submit(function()
{

    var f = $('#theInput').val(); // input value

    if(f == TRUE)
    {
        alert('Lorem ipsum');

        return false;
    }
    else // If f is FALSE
    {
        $.post('/php/check.php',{check: f, function(data){myFunction(data);});

        function myFunction(data)
        {

            if(data == 'false')
            {
                // Do something
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something
                return true;
            }
        }

        return myFunction();
    }

 });
```

I have tried this, but it is still not returning a value to the form from 'return myFunction()'

```
$('#theForm').submit(function()
{

    var f = $('#theInput').val(); // input value

    if(f == true)
    {
        alert('Lorem ipsum');

        return false; // Stop default form action
    }
    else // If f is FALSE
    {

     var request = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/php/checkArea.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: f},
        dataType: "text"
        });

        request.done(function(data) {
            myFunction(data);
        });

        function myFunction(data)
        {

            if(data == 'false')
            {
                // Do something
                return false; // Stop default form action
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something
                return true; // YES PLEASE, do the default form action
            }
        }

        return myFunction();
    }

 });
```

---

**I finally figured out a solution, with help from you, regarding the async part.**

```
$('#theForm').submit(function()
{

    var f = $('#theInput').val(); // input value

    if(f == true)
    {
        alert('Lorem ipsum');

        return false; // Stop default form action
    }
    else // If f is FALSE
    {

     var request = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/php/checkArea.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: f},
        dataType: "text"
        });

        request.done(function(data) {
            globalData = data; // Global variable
        });

        function myFunction(globalData)
        {

            if(globalData == 'false')
            {
                // Do something
                return false; // Stop default form action
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something
                return true; // YES PLEASE, do the default form action
            }
        }

        return myFunction(globalData); // Call the function with the global variable
    }

 });
```

**This works perfectly :-)**

Comment: Your myFunction() is been run before your `$.post` Ajax call returned a value. use the async: false with your $.post

Comment: Now try my edited solution below. It should work now except you are doing something wrong.

Comment: change this line `data: {data: f},` to `data : f,` in the edited question of yours

Answer (score 2):

This part should do what you want:

```
if(f == TRUE)
{
    alert('Lorem ipsum');

    return false;
}
```

This, however, should not:

```
    $.post('/php/check.php',{check: f, function(data){myFunction(data);});

    function myFunction(data)
    {

        if(data == 'false')
        {
            // Do something
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something
            return true;
        }
    }

    return myFunction();
```

The $.post will always return **immediately**. myFunction will be called when the Ajax call is finished, but by then you *have already returned* from the .submit block!

You may check out the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which have a setting to make it synchronous (set `async` to `false`). This may lock the browser from doing anything else while waiting for the Ajax call, but it's the only way to make a synchronous call.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DIV` that will hold your `false` or `true` value from the `$.ajax`

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now structure your javascript

```
   $('#theForm').submit( function() {

      var f = $('#theInput').val(); // input value

      if(f == TRUE) {

         alert('Lorem ipsum');
         return false;

      } else { // If f is FALSE

         var rVal = $('div#result');

         $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : f,
            url : '/php/check.php',
            context: rVal,
            async : false,

            success : function (msg) {
               (msg == 'false') ?  $(this).html('FALSE') : $(this).html(msg);
            }

         });

        function myFunction(data) {

            if(data == 'FALSE'){
               // Do something
               return false;
            } else {
               // Do something
               return true;
            }

        }

       return myFunction( rVal.html() );

      }
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the else part i want to let the form know if it should do its default action or not. Your code is returning false no matter what. So the form will never do its default action.

Comment: I only rewrite your code from your question above regardless of what the return will be and what will happen after the returned value. you can throw-in more light by adding to your question above.

Answer (score 0):

Case-sensitivity may be an issue. Javascript uses `true` and `false`, not `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

In your `else` clause, you have a callback for your `POST` which handles the data returned. However, the callback `myFunction` will be run after the code has reached `return myFunction()` which — as it doesn't have an argument — will cause the anonymous function to return `true`.

You need to make your asynchronous call synchronous, but even then, where is `myFunction` returning its result to?

You might try forcing `myFunction` to return its result to the right context like the following (I prefer to declare the function before it's used), but you may still run into synchronicity issues. It appears from the docs that `$.post` cannot be forced to be synchronous.

```
else // If f is FALSE
{
    function myFunction(data)
    {
        if(data == 'false')
        {
            // Do something
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something
            return true;
        }
    }
    return ($.post('/php/check.php',{check: f}, function(data){myFunction(data);}));
}
```

Comment: myFunction is returning the value to the form, so it knows if it should do a default action or not.

Comment: @suer977150: I don't believe it is. The last `return` statement does that.

Comment: Ok, but thats my problem. In the else part i want to let the form know if it should do its default action or not. But i can't seem to get the return value out to the form...

Comment: @user977150: Suggested solution, but I can't test it. Note also that in your original code you are missing a `}` from `{check:f}`